# Unable to Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

We recently purchased an Azure App Service Certificate. I created a new Key Vault Store in the set up process for this certificate, and imported the certificate.

Now I'm trying to create a local copy of an App Service Certificate, using the powershell script provided here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/

However, I get an error:

> Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot find the Active Directory object '' in tenant 'my tenant id'. Please make sure that the user or application service principal you are authorizing is registered in the curren
>   t subscription's Azure Active directory. The TenantID displayed by the cmdlet 'Get-AzureRmContext' is the current subsc
>   ription's Azure Active directory.
>   At C:\Projekt\Certificates\Azure\copyasc.ps1:22 char:1...

I'm not sure what else is relevant, but here's a few notes:

- The username I'm sending into the failing Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -UserPrincipalName temp@outlook.com, corresponds to the username of the only user I see in the default directory of Azure Active Directory.
- This user's ObjectId is in the list of access policies for the keyvault (I see this by adding -Debug to the cmdlet that fails).
- There are no keys in the keyvault. There is one (unmanaged) secret, the certificate.

Some threads mention stuff about AD applications. I'm not sure I understood what I read about these. Is this something I need to do when creating a keyvault?

Hope someone can help me? :)

Comment: Does it work now, the root reason for your error log is that your user is not a Azure AD account, for B2C user, UserPrincipalName should add `#EXE#@<your AD name>`.

Comment: If you know your user Object id, `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ResourceGroupName $keyVaultResourceGroupName -VaultName $keyVaultName -ObjectId $userobjectid -PermissionsToSecrets get` should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error log,  your `UserPrincipalName` value is wrong. Please execute following command to get the  `UserPrincipalName`.

```
Get-Azureaduser
```

`temp@outlook.com` is not a Azure AD account, its userprincipalname should be `temp@outlook.com#EXT#@<your AD>`.

Or you could replace `UserPrincipalName` to user's object id.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ResourceGroupName $keyVaultResourceGroupName -VaultName $keyVaultName -ObjectId $userobjectid -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

Comment: Hi, currently, could you get UserPrincipalName in your Azure AD?

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the ObjectId as you suggested and got the certificate.